# Can performance of newing objects in a loop be improved

Tags: java

What can I do to improve the performance of this code?  I have to create 
an object for each item I get back with a query SQL query which returns an 
array of values.  I don't know if pre-allocating the objects would help 
much since I'm newing up an object every time I retrieve a result item.
Also I'm storing the objects in a map of ids => objects and ids are being 
stored in a list of ids for faster access later.

```
        java.util.Vector<Integer> resultList = new java.util.Vector<Integer>();
        while (result.next()) {
            Ptrobject ptrobject = new Ptrobject(connection());

            DataValue[] values = result.getValues();

            int idx = 0;
            ptrobject.id           = values[idx++].getInt();
            ptrobject.unty        = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.tumCode     = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.eldName     = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.atTD        = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.stOper      = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.aseName     = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.aseNbr      = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.erator      = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.odFM        = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.marks       = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.ate         = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.mCode       = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.jectLabel     = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.jectName      = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.jectNumber    = values[idx++].getString();
            ptrobject.ud             = (Timestamp) values[idx++].getPtrobject();

            s_cache.getMap().put(ptrobject.id, ptrobject);
            resultList.add(ptrobject.id);
        }
```

Comment: **DON'T USE A `VECTOR`**. I'm not joking, this is a **deprecated** collection type and is very slow. Also, what is `s_cache`?

Comment: What tests did you use to determine that it was `new` that is causing your problems?

Comment: How do you know that the slowness is in the instantiation? Maybe you need to tune the SQL query, or chance the batch fetch size, or... As with everything in performance, **you must measure.**

Comment: I think at this level you can speed up parsing of sql, try for example to increase cursor fetch size `Statement.setFetchSize(..)` to 100, 1000 or more. Does connection() method creates any new sql connections?

Comment: Use a profiler to measure the spent time. Sometimes this is all you need to get optimization ideas and it prevents you from wasting time with trying unneccessary optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

Put the object definitions out of the while statement

```
Ptrobject ptrobject;
DataValue[] values;
int idx;
while (result.next()) {
        ptrobject = new Ptrobject(connection());
        values = result.getValues();
        idx=0;
        .....
```

I know that minimum scope say not to do this way, but if you want speed, that is.
Here it is a benckmark for inside vs outside declaration.

http://www.gunduru.com/post/107249109253/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop

Comment: If an object is declared inside a loop the memory for the object is allocated each time and the initialization for the object is performed. The initialization may not take that much time but the memory allocation will be. But nowadays I think that the compiler makes this kind of optimizations.

Comment: Won't this cause the code to put the same object over and over in the same result list?

Comment: No, you reuse the reference not the content.

Comment: This is completely wrong, and makes no difference. The memory is allocated either way, the reference is reused. It also violates the "minimum scope" rule that one should apply to all garbage collected languages.

Comment: Check http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/06/14/10-best-tips-to-conserve-memory-in-java-programs.html . Point 1 and 4

Comment: @PabloGallegoFalcón that random link is also wrong. On many points.

Comment: Minimum scope rule is for garbage collection optimization, what I suggest is better for speed. But I think that nowadays compiler will generate the same code for both solutions.

Comment: Here you have a benchmark http://www.gunduru.com/post/107249109253/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop

Comment: That benchmark shows that it saved 500ns over 100 million loops. It's completely pointless.

Comment: I know, but here @Flethuseo asks for speed up

Comment: @PabloGallegoFalcón Yes, I did, the gain won't mean much of anything because I don't have 100 million items, but it's still useful information.